# How to open Excel workbook without updating external data sources (but keeping it enabled)?

Tags: vba, excel, macros, database-connection

I have some workbooks, which starts with automatic macros and data refreshing (and, pre-empting some suggestions, these workbooks need to work like that, because I'm starting them automatically from Windows scheduler and I need them to perform tasks without any action on the user's part).

When I need to check/update some formulas, SQL query or layout, I just open a workbook **holding [Shift] key** and it prevents triggering macros in Workbook_Open / Auto_Open events etc., which is great.

The problem is that there are still some external data sources which are automatically refreshed during the opening. In some of these workbooks queries take a long while to accomplish and I need to wait a minute or two before I can edit a workbook.

Is there any way I could open a workbook with both macros and data refreshing disabled? Or, perhaps, any simple way to cancel executing a query?

Comment: could you pause the macro?

Answer (score 2):

Go Into the **Excel Options**
navigate to **Trust Center** then T**rust Center Settings** and go to 
**External Content**.

You'll see the Security Settings for Data Connections and Workbook Links. **Disable** both.

Restart Excel and you're done.

In Office 2010, go to the same External Content menu, and select Disable all Data Connections as well as Disable automatic update of workbook links.

Comment: Moosli, thanks for your suggestion. It works, indeed, however I would like something less complicated. It would be perfect to find something like opening with Shift key or some keys combination to immediately stop queries. Switching aforementioned Excel settings on and off seems to take more time than just waiting for query to be executed... :)

Comment: @kurp You have a button in word and when you press them, it will refresh all your data

Answer (score 2):

After inserting the code into the proper modules run `CreateAltStartVBS`.  `CreateAltStartVBS` will create a VBScript file (AltStart.vbs) in the workbooks folder.  When you run `AltStart.vbs` it will start your workbook bypassing your opening macros and disabling the Connections from refreshing.

### Workbook Module

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   EnableRefresh True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If getSwitch = "/z" Then
        EnableRefresh False
        Exit Sub
    End Sub
    'Normal code goes here
End Sub

Sub EnableRefresh(Enable As Boolean)
    Dim conn As Object
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        conn.ODBCConnection.EnableRefresh = Enable
    Next
End Sub
```

### Standard Module

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit

Declare Function GetCommandLine Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As Long
Declare Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (MyDest As Any, MySource As Any, ByVal MySize As Long)

Function CmdToSTr(Cmd As Long) As String
    Dim Buffer() As Byte
    Dim StrLen As Long

    If Cmd Then
        StrLen = lstrlenW(Cmd) * 2
        If StrLen Then
            ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
            CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal Cmd, StrLen
            CmdToSTr = Buffer
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function getSwitch()
    Dim CmdRaw As Long
    Dim CmdLine As String

    CmdRaw = GetCommandLine
    CmdLine = CmdToSTr(CmdRaw)
    getSwitch = Split(CmdLine, Chr(34))(2)

End Function

Sub EnableConnections(Enable As Boolean)
    Dim conn As Object
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        conn.ODBCConnection.EnableRefresh = Enable
    Next
End Sub

Sub CreateAltStartVBS()
    Dim myFile As String
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AltStart.vbs"
    Open myFile For Output As #1

    Print #1, "Dim objShell"
    Print #1, "Set objShell = CreateObject (""WScript.Shell"")"
    Print #1, "objShell.Run ""excel.exe /z """ & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34)
    Print #1, "Set objShell = Nothing"

    Close #1

End Sub
```